# How stable is Wicket 8? What is supposed timeline?

Tags: wicket

Few days ago (September 2017) announcement say Wicket 8.0.0-M7 is released.

How stable and tested is '8' line? Can be used in low-scale production intranet?
Assume after this step adopted sources cannot be back-migrated to '7' version

Exist kind of unofficial release plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we are currently tackling the [issue](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Joda-time-dependency-td4678707.html) of removing the Joda time dependency from wicket-datetime module. Hopefully we should manage it in the very next weeks. This is the blocking issue that prevents from releasing Wicket 8. Apart from this we don't plan to change Wicket API any further.
Wicket 8 is stable and we haven't found issues in our running applications.

Still, M7 contains a bug with page store which affected 7.x as well. 
It has been fixed in 7.9.0 but so far no 8.x version has been release with this fix, although it has been applied to the source code. 
Since you want to implement a low scale internal application you can consider to use snapshot version 8.0.0-SNAPSHOT which is the very last build of Wicket 8 code.

UPDATE: Wicket 8.0.0-M8 has been released few weeks ago. Joda Time has been removed and the bug with page store has been solved, hence M8 can be used as reference version for Wicket 8. The GA version should come out before the end of the year.